# "Petabyte scale" Redshift uses more than 500 MB Memory to sort 848.00 KB of Data

Tags: amazon-redshift

I've noticed quite large memory allocation in a step of execution plan, and that was quite confusing. 
[image]

Is there any ideas, why such stuff is happening ?

Query is a straight select *, row_number() over(partition by column1) from table where sort_key=value. The rrs filtered dataset is 1000 rows. Then sorting applied.

Comment: Your question does not include enough information for someone to be able to answer it.  What is the query? What are the tables? What is the data volume? What is the entire execution plan? I explained in another unrelated answer why Redshift will read a minimum of one block per slice per column for a given query. The behaviour you are seeing is most likely normal, but it is tough to discuss it in greater detail without understanding the full context. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090962/why-does-redshift-need-to-do-a-full-table-scan-to-find-the-max-value-of-the-dist/39102204#39102204

Comment: Why do you mean using 657 MB memory to sort 1000 rows is normal ?

Comment: It seems to me that this is just allocated memory, but not memory used for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

That is the working memory allocated for the query queue slot. If you change your query range from few rows to 100 thousand rows, it will show you the same working memory.